# Como eu removo o autocomplete do typeahead e deixa só as sugestões em baixo

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead

[image: Input]

[image: Html]

```
    $('.typeahead_oque').typeahead({minLength: 0}, {
        source: categoriestextFunction,
        name: 'categories'
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Só uma questão de consultar a [documentação oficial](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#options):

> **Options**
>
> `hint` – *If `false`, the typeahead will not show a hint. Defaults to `true`*.

Ou seja, basta fazer:

```
$('.typeahead_oque').typeahead(
  {
    minLength: 0, 
    hint: false
  }, {
    source: categoriestextFunction,
    name: 'categories'
  }
);
```

Comment: Deu certo aqui, muito obrigado =).
Sou novato no site, não sei colocar como resolvido.

Comment: @SamuelFaria Então recomendo que faça o [tour] e acesse a [help], em especial a página [O que eu devo fazer se alguém responder minha pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)